# Tensorflow / Keras categorical encoding

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a question regarding the category encoding in keras/tensorflow.
In the example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers

in this example a categorical encoding is performed:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/preprocessing_layers#categorical_columns

Here the two categories cat or dog are mapped into four dummy variables. Why are four and not two variables needed for this? I have the same problem with my applications.